# How do I emulate an Internet Explorer to be uninstalled?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, mime-types

ALL,

Is there a way to emulate a disappearing of an IE from the live system?

I would like to test the fallback I'm trying to implement for MimeType information. I know it's possible to strip down Windows to make it without Internet Explorer. Or maybe I just need to edit MimeType information on my system?

Thank you.

Comment: Other than the brevity of your question, I don't understand the down votes. This is for testing, right?

Comment: @slugster, yes, it is for testing. Thats why I said "emulate".

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add a bit of detail then, before it gets down voted to oblivion and/or closed.

Comment: Shouldn't be closed IMO

Comment: The idea is flawed. You can remove the browser UI, but not Trident (the DLLs which do the real work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I can change the registry to do that.

I don't remember exact key name, but can dig this info up if someone interested.